# Unusual waves and one of its parameter

Tags: waves, frequency, wavelength, string

I'm messing up with this java app on the web about waves on a string and i'm really curious about something.        The java app is the following  :

http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/wave-on-a-string/wave-on-a-string_en.html

Putting the Damping to "0" and choosing the "Manual mode" ( the others are "Oscilate" and "Pulse" ) i'm realizing the action of arbitrarily lifting the left-end point of the string ( and then letting it stay fixed high, not returning it back ) and i'm noticing that a wave ( as a definition of traveling energy ) is propagated through the string ( i know this is not the usual periodic sinusoidal wave, but rather a random wave that dies off quickly ) .

But the thing is that there seems to be a parameter ( calling it parameter S and a  parameter that has to do with how much space it takes on the string )  of that wave that is related to the velocity that i do the lifting of the left-end point ( which is in turn related to the size of the interval of time for the lifting, considering a fixed heigth ).

Whenever the lifting is fast ( equivalent to a short interval of time for the lifting ) , that parameter S is short, as showed in the following image :

[image]

Whenever the lifting is slow ( equivalent to a large lifting interval of time ) , that parameter S is large as showed in the following image :

[image]

So, my question ... Is there a formal name for that parameter S?
It seems so similar to the wave-length ( a parameter that commonly refers to a sinusoidal repetitive wave ) ,  could i call it that ?
 Are there any resources ( internet sites, books, whatever ) that talk about the wave-length of arbitrary waves ?
 I can only find information  about wave-length in the context of the usual sinusoidal repetitive waves ( the wave i'm considering is here is not repetitive [ because it consists simply of a lifting ] and not necessarily sinusoidal in pattern )  .

Moreover, can the famous equation $v = \lambda. f  $   be also applied to this kind of wave ?
    I was thinking that with Fourier Transform we could decompose that wave into a linear combination of sinusoidal ones,  and then each sinusoidal wave would have its parameters  v, $\lambda$, f   ,  so actually there would be actually n equations of the form     $v = \lambda. f  $  ,  corresponding to the n sinusoidal waves in which my unusual wave is linearly decomposed.
But still ,what all of this have to do with that parameter S ?

I'm trying to abstract the concept of wave away from the usual sinusoidal repetitive waves because if a wave is defined , roughly,  as traveling energy,  it doesn't necessarily need to be the repetitive sinusoidal wave that is so common in the literature.   But it seems like i'm not having a so easy time to abstract the parameters of wave ( the wave-length and wave-velocity, for instance ) to those more abstract and general waves.    And finally, i can't figure it out what that parameter S really is ( its formal name  and more precise definitions  about it ).

Any help is highly appreciated, i'm trying to figure this out for weeks.

Sorry for the size of the question and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: To me, the rising part looks like half of a sawtooth-wave ... or perhaps a sluggish square-wave.